# Как узнать, что одна ветка полностью содержит изменения другой ветки?

Tags: git

Скажем, вот у нас ветка:
release/1

Через какое-то время от нее создается ветка release/2 и в нее начинает заливаться новый контент.
В тоже время, в ветку release/1 добавляются всякие фиксы.

Вот наступает время выпуска release/2 и нужно понять, что она содержит все то, что было выпущено для release/1.

Какие способы определения есть? Я пытался по дереву понять, но по моему, это сложно.

Есть еще вариант, вмержить в 2 ветку 1.

Какие еще варианты есть?

Comment: "По определению" в 2 будет вся ветка 1 до момента бранча. После этого она никак не может "содержит все то, что было выпущено для release/1" без слияния с ней. Так что единственный вариант достичь требуемого (?) это "вмержить в 2 ветку 1".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/501407/4827341

Answer (score 1):

`git log release/2..release/1` вернет все коммиты, что есть в `release/1`, но которых нет в `release/2`.

Если пусто - значит все слито.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с `git log ...` очевидно неверный из-за возможного разрешения конфликтов внутри слияния. Поэтому необходимо пользоваться одной из следующих команд (скорее всего второй):

1. `git branch --contains COMMIT_ID_на_момент_слияния`
2. `git merge-base release/1 release/2`

в зависимости от начальных условий.